# Can the capital 'Y' be rendered isomorphically? (i.e. as a bigger version as the lowercase one)

Tags: capitalization, writing, handwriting

I sometimes find videos or educational websites that teach children to write the uppercase Y just like the lowercase one, but in a larger size; just like in this picture here:

[image: Image of a large letter Y]

Is this correct or is it a common mistake?

As far as I know, the capital Y has only one form, which is with a straight vertical downward line.

So, my question is: could the CAPITAL letter Y be written like the small one but in a bigger size just like the picture?

---

P.S. I'm **not** asking about cursive handwriting at all. Please keep cursive handwriting out of this topic.

Comment: There are very few rules about "correct" handwriting, particularly when it comes to the details of letter shapes, provided that the result looks reasonably neat and comprehensible.

Comment: We can close this as a "matter of opinion".

Comment: Dave Gibbons who lettered *Watchmen* used a Y similar to this, with a tail going to the left - [example](https://ew.com/article/2012/02/01/watchmen-prequels-exclusive-details/). Lettering a legendary comic book is probably as good as it gets when it comes to handwriting these days.

Comment: @GEdgar So the answer is "yes" :)

Comment: Besides "Y" and "y" size, the main difference is the vertical alignment : The lower case "y" has a descender under the baseline.

Comment: One may mention in passing, for whatever it's worth, that only the slant form is correct in Cyrillic (I believe the erect form is *also* used, contrasting with it, in some non-Slavic languages).

Comment: @GEdgar My close-vote is there. But I don't see any others. // Is the backwards B in ABBA the way they spell it 'correct'? Who decides? This is almost like 'deciding' whether green ink may be used in official documents.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a font currently on my computer
[image: FONT]

Comment: +1 Nice...the exception proves the rule. Also Comic Sans is considered ... informal.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a capital *Y* both ways:

> [image]

I've seen both used; although the vertical version is more common in my experience, I personally use the slanted one.

The pen company *BIC* did a study where they averaged several thousands of people's handwritten renderings of the alphabet. (Which you can read about [here](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2687465/The-worlds-handwriting-ONE-font-Typeface-reveals-average-human-writes-letter-alphabet.html).) This is what the averaged *Y* looks like, and as you can see, the vertical version is more standard, but the isomorphic one is still seen quite often:

> [image]

Both are correct, in that both are clear: you can't really say that one version is 'wrong' or 'mistaken'.

---

That said, you could make the argument that, etymologically, the vertical version is more accurate, as our *y* comes from the Greek ypsilon, which came from the Phoenician *waw*, which were both commonly rendered in the vertical fashion.

This, for instance, is the earliest known specimen of the Hebrew alphabet, from 10 BCE. The rightmost character is the *waw*, and it is clearly written with a vertical line:

> [image] [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oldest_Hebrew_Inscription_X_BC.jpg)

But that's not necessarily a very good argument to make, akin to saying that my grandmother's delicious pie is *awful*.

Comment: 'Correct' and 'wrong' are fightin words. But 'is common', 'is rare', is data driven, and 'looks funny' is opinion that can be grounded in data. An asymmetrical capital 'Y' looks funny, and is rare (doesn't exist?) in any font I am aware of. And if you find one, excellent, it's still rare enough that it looks funny. In handwriting, maybe some people do the capital asymmetrically to be artistic (maybe?), but it would seem very strange to have penmanship learners be taught that way.

Comment: @Mitch People learning handwriting seldom duplicate fonts - I certainly didn't get taught to write my "a" with a hook on top. There are fonts with an asymmetrical capital Y - both Greybeard and GEdgar have posted examples ranging from Blackletter/Fraktur to Comic Sans.

Comment: @StuartF Good point... there's a big difference between the great variety of handwriting and the much much smaller set of artisanally created fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the font: Lowercase "y" invariably has the tail below the line.

As a general guidance, standard printed fonts have the tail of the uppercase "Y" above the line. Cursive and decorative fonts tend to have the tail of the "Y" below the line.

[image: Fonts]

The position of the tail of the Y in handwriting depends entirely on the writer.

Comment: There *are* fonts without descenders, see [Are there "bi-form" fonts that don't have descenders?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38521/are-there-bi-form-fonts-that-dont-have-descenders) Apart from design, this was common in early computer graphics with a limited number of raster lines.